# Github Actions to see changed files

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to use actions to post a comment on a PR if a file has changed but my action is unable to see the changes.

```
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    permissions:
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Get all changed files and echo alert
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: *******************
        run: |

          git diff --name-status
```

or if I change it to **git status** it outputs a message saying no changes working tree is clean, but I know one file has changed.

I tried using v1 instead of v2 but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas on what i am doing wrong or how I can get this working?

Comment: Do you want to post a comment if a specific file has changed? If so, you can maybe use the [`paths` filter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore) instead of trying to figure out manually what files have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout is just "checking out" clean repository state for a given commit or PR.

If you expect to get changes files from PR, you can do it by using external actions, for examples:

```
- name: Get changed files using defaults
  id: changed-files
  uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v32
- name: List all added files
  run: |
     for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs. modified_files }}; do
        echo "$file was modified."
     done
```

Comment: can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943923/dorny-paths-filter-does-not-get-the-correct-action

Answer (score 3):

Use Github contexts: [Learn GitHub Actions Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)

Here is the command you probably need:

```
git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.after }} ${{ github.event.before }}
```

Also, you could affect the whole action by setting `paths` at the beginning of an action:

```
name: Action #1

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - <folder>/** // action will be triggered by push to the main branch AND when there are changed files in <folder>

  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - <folder>/*.js // action will be triggered only on pull-requests AND when any .js files in <folder> have been changed
```